# Switch order of three "words"

Tags: key-bindings

When writing code, I often have code of the form

`variableA operator variableB`

and I would like to edit it to be

`variableB operator variableA.`

Right now, I do this by deleting/pasting `variableB` to be in front of `variableA` and then deleting/pasting `operator` to be in between them. Is there a slicker way to do this in Vim?

Comment: Count how many keystrokes you need to do what you're doing. In my case, it's `diW2WviWpBBhP` which is 13. I would argue it's enough for getting by. Otherwise, create a leader mapping.

Answer (score 2):

```
variableA operator variableB
   ^ cursor here
```

```
diwmmwwvep`mP
```

**explanation**

- `diw` delete variableA into register "
- `mm` mark current position
- `ww` move cursor to variableB
- `vep` replace variableB with variableA, also set register " to variableB
- `m go back to marked position
- `P` paste variableB

It's awkward to swap this way. 
I recommand [tommcdo/vim-exchange](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-exchange)

With that plugin all you need is

```
cxiwww.
```

Comment: That seems like so much work! This is why I started learning the ex commands better

Comment: Yes, i never do it manually, ex commands also won't do you any good during daily swaping.

Comment: disagree. With practice it’s a fine technique and applicable broadly.

Comment: No, in this case, you can't beat https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-exchange.  how do you compete with  `cxiwww.` ? it even has a "." repeat.

Comment: Mappings, macros, etc. Not that hard. But its also not something i do often enough to need a broad fix for.

Comment: Im not spending time optimizing the rare, easy stuff

Comment: Disagree, this is not rare, it's swaping, everyone swaps, it's also not easy without plugin. I highly doubt one can create Mappings or macros that work in a more natural way than https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, via search and replace:

```
:s/\v(variableA) (operator) (variableB)/\3 \2 \1
```

- `\v` is for very magic to make the parens easier
- The parens make capture groups, referenced in the substitution to flip the order

You can add a range at the beginning of `:s` (e.g., `:%s...` to operate on the entire file) and flags at the end (e.g., `...\1/g` to operate on all matches in each line).

Pattern needs adjusting if situation is more complex. See `:h pattern`

Comment: Nice use of capture groups, but it is not practically any faster than writing out `variableB operator variableA`, because I need to write out `(variableA) (operator) (variableB)`! I can't even yank and paste into the command line, because I still need to go back and add the parentheses.

Comment: @The_Anomaly two suggestion: (1) yank it and open the command line window (`q:`) instead, so you can add parens faster; and (2) use vim-surround from tpope (on github) to make adding said parens really fast. Combine with repeat.vim for maximum effect. Finally, note that by making the regex smarter (`\v(\k+) (operator) (\k+)`, for example) you do save typing time.

Comment: Very nice. And wow, `q:` is blowing my mind, not sure how I did not know about this...

Comment: @The_Anomaly, if you didn't know about `q:` I'm pretty sure you are also gonna like `:h c_CTRL-F`